# Use Template Literal as an object

Tags: javascript

I have an input at the end of my table and I want it to have a different ids for each row. I made something like this:

```
`<td><input type="number" name="quantity${article.ID}" id="quantity${article.ID}" min="1" max="5"></td>`
```

This works well, as when I look in the html, it gives me something like: quantity1, quantity2 etc.

The thing is, when i try to call these ids dynamically, it returns null. Here is the full javascript code:

```
//load JSON file
var articles = ""
var txt = ""
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    txt = JSON.parse(articles);
    console.log(txt);

    processArticles(txt);

    processForm(txt);

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","../articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processArticles(article) {

  var tableStart = `
    <h2>Liste des articles</h2>
    <form id="formtable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Prix-Retour</th>
        <th>Quantitée maximale</th>
        <th>Projet</th>
        <th>Quantitée</th>
      </tr>`;

  var tableEnd = `
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>`;

  function articlesTemplate(article) {
    return `
          <tr>
            <td>${article.ID}</td>
            <td>${article.Article }</td>
            <td>${article.Prix}</td>
            <td>${article.PrixRetour}</td>
            <td>${article.QuantiteeMaximale}</td>
            <td>${article.Projet}</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity${article.ID}" id="quantity${article.ID}" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
      `;

  }

  let mctxt=txt.filter(value=>
    value.Projet=="mc");
    document.getElementById("tablemc").innerHTML = `
      ${tableStart}
      ${mctxt.map(articlesTemplate).join("")}
      ${tableEnd}
      `;
    ;
}

function processForm(article) {
  var form = document.getElementById('formtable');
  var quantity = document.getElementById([`quantity${article.ID}`]);

  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(quantity);
 };
}
```

The quantity variable returns as null when I log it. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Try checking how you're making the Id. Does in need to be backticks? - I'm not sure myself but just a thought.

Comment: @MichaelKnight I'm pretty sure it need some as it is a template literal. I don't think I can call the ${article.ID} without it. I'll still check, maybe I can

Comment: Never mind I didn't see you using them at the top.  Maybe check the template literal you're making to getbyid is correct? I.e. console.log it

Comment: @MichaelKnight well when I check the HTML, the id does say quantity1, I just can't access it with get by id dynamically

Comment: are you sure that processForm is called with the correct article object? 
because it works for me

Comment: Well it is called with the same article as the function containing the table so i wouldn't think that's the problem

Comment: @Louis How are you "checking the html"? What you showed was only a string, it's not yet part of the DOM.

Comment: ^^^What they said. Probably the generated HTML is not part of the DOM time by the time the JS is being called.

Comment: I just updated my post to show the entire file. The string i was calling before is part of the table. I think it might have to do with mapping like i do in the first function, but not in the second one

Comment: Well I somehow got it to work by changing my last function to this: ```function processForm(article) {
  var form = document.getElementById('formtable');

  function articleID(article) {
    var quantity = document.getElementById(`quantity${article.ID}`);
    return quantity.value;
  };

  let quant = txt.filter(value=>
    value.Projet=="mc");

  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(quant.map(articleID).join(""));
 };
}```